# Acessing elements of permutation group in sagemath

Tags: python, sage

if I consider an element of a permutation group in sagemath, for example
`SymmetricGroup(7).list()[1900]`,

which is `(1,6)(2,5,4)(3,7)`,

I can get the cycles like elements from a list, so

`SymmetricGroup(7).list()[1900][1]`,

will return `(2,5,4)`.

However, I do not find a way, to get the elements of this object, as it looks like a tuple, but actually it is not, as

`SymmetricGroup(7).list()[1900][1][1]`

gives the error `"list index out of range"`, instead of returning 5.
Does somebody know, how I can get direct access to the entries of the cycle?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I used tab-completion to find the method `cycle_tuples`:

```
sage: a = SymmetricGroup(7).list()[1900]                                                  
sage: a                                                                                   
(1,6)(2,5,4)(3,7)
sage: a.cycles()                                                                          
[(1,6), (2,5,4), (3,7)]
sage: type(a.cycles()[1]) # not what we want
<class 'sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup_element.SymmetricGroupElement'>
sage: a.cycle_tuples()
[(1, 6), (2, 5, 4), (3, 7)]
sage: type(a.cycle_tuples()[1]) # what we want!
<class 'tuple'>
sage: b = a.cycle_tuples()[1]
sage: b
(2, 5, 4)
sage: b[1]
5
```

(By "using tab-completion," I mean typing "a." and then hitting the TAB key.) `cycle_tuples` is [documented here](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup_element.html#sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup_element.PermutationGroupElement.cycle_tuples).